# If my application frequently writes out huge files what would be the most memory efficient way of dealing with the files?

Tags: file

Would it be beneficial for me to create a tmp file then rename it once the whole file is written to ?

Comment: What are your concerns about memory efficiency?

Comment: Basically the content to be written is huge so it isnt possible to write the data all at once but in small chunks

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard technique used by many applications to ensure that the file you see is always up to date as writing it in parts can take a while if the file is very large.

Write out to temp file, close the file descriptor and force a sync call to make sure that the contents are written to disk (because of write buffering) and then do a rename on the temp file to the one you want to write.

Comment: What are the advantages of writing to a tmp file as opposed to a regular file ?? If you write to a regular file why can't u be sure that the file will always be up to date ?

Comment: Because of write buffering to the disk and the fact that it takes time to write to a file so if a read occurs before it's done then you can read data that isn't completely up to date yet.

Comment: So you are saying tmp file is write buffered and regular file is not? Can you elaborate, i want to know how is performance better if you write to a tmp file ?

Comment: Well the thing is lets say you're in the middle of writing the file and someone tries to read it, they will read an incomplete file (which may be bad). The changes are actually not flushed to the disk immediately so that may do something you don't want either. The performance isn't better it's just that when the file is done writing and you rename you can be sure the file is completely written.